# android ListView is refreshed after opening keyboard

Tags: android-fragments, android-listview, android-softkeyboard

i have list view , each child is text view where there is text other text view with translation of text and Edit text which will be visible if push on left edit button
when i like edit app get focus in edit text opening key board and hear refreshing all list view

Comment: Perhaps opening the keyboard is calling onPause on your fragment/activity. If you are loading your content in onResume then it might be causing your data to refresh.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to add you ListView into a TabActivity you also have to set android:windowSoftInputMode=”adjustPan” for the TabActivity definition in the manifest.
`<activity android:name= ".yourActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>`